# Printing a whole pointer

Tags: c, pointers, encryption, malloc

I'm trying to get a long bunch of integers as input like :

111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003

But using arrays not allowed. So I decide to take them with the help of pointers.

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 each of these integers represent ‘ ’, ‘-’, ‘_’, ‘|’, ‘/’, ‘\’, ‘O‘

This means, 1 should be translated into ' '(space) or 2 should be '-'

I am asked to write a function that reads such integer files, decrypt them as above and visualize
the new form. Before translating them to a new form, I want to be sure that I take them correctly and I want to be able to print them correctly, also.

```
char *p = malloc(1000);
scanf("%1000s",p);
for(; *p != '\n'; p++)
    printf("%c",*p);
```

The compiler gives me this output when I entered `abc` as input:
`abcabc`

Why is that so? Is using malloc like that okay? Don't forget, arrays are not allowed!

Comment: `%s` won't store newline charcter `'\n'`. `*p != '\n'` should be `*p != '\0'`.

Comment: Also `%1000s` should be `%999s` or `malloc(1000)` should be `malloc(1001)` to reserve a room for terminating null-character.

Comment: Oh,really it solved :)  Thanks...I also have another question,I don't want to enter a value into malloc function because it looks silly!Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Hmmm... using `calloc()` instead to avoid using `malloc()`?

Comment: Are you aware that when you use a pointer as the return value from `malloc`, you use it as a pointer the the first element of an **array**?

Comment: I'll search about calloc,too.Again,thanks for this rapid help!

Comment: Or just use plain static array if it is acceptable according to what will be done with `p` in non-disclosed part of your code.

Comment: @SergeBallesta So you said with this form of my code I'm using arrays?I didn't recognize that.So what should I do to make this transform without using arrays?

Comment: @nicholai_hel: It was just a remark. Without using arrays at all, you simply cannot not process sequences of objects, because pointer arithmetics is only valid inside an array. I assume that the requirement was to only use dynamic arrays, else only magic could help...

Comment: Doesn't the "no arrays" restriction mean that you should process the input character by character?

Comment: @dratenik Actually I thought like you,too.But required input is consisting of so much integers and I couldn't see any enter seperated or space seperated part in that input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description of the problem, you shouldn't need read and store 1000 characters at a time - you should be able to read each character and translate on the fly:

```
for ( int c = fgetc( input ); c != EOF; c = fgetc( input ) )
{ 
  // transform c and output the result here
}
```

You can add a print statement for debugging:

```
for ( int c = fgetc( input ); c != EOF; c = fgetc( input ) )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "%c", c ); 
  // transform c and output the result here
}
```

That's the usual approach for filters or translators like this.

Having said that, there are a few things I want to point out with your code.

As others pointed out in the comments, you need to reserve at least one element for the string terminator, so you either need to allocate 1001 elements and read 1000, or allocate 1000 elements and read 999:

```
char *p = malloc( 1000 );
scanf( "%999s", p );
```

But there's another problem - the way you've written your loop

```
for(; *p != '\n'; p++)
    printf("%c",*p);
```

you're modifying `p` - when you pass that as an argument to `free` it will fail because it's not the pointer value that `malloc` returned.  You'll need to retain the pointer returned from `malloc` and either use a separate pointer to walk through the array, or use array index notation:

```
for ( char *tmp = p; *tmp != 0; tmp++ )
  printf( "%c", *tmp );
```

or

```
for( size_t i = 0; p[i] != 0; i++ )
  printf( "%c", p[i] );
```

Also, `%s` tells `scanf` to stop taking input at the next whitespace character - it will not store `'\n'` or any other whitespace character to the string.  You'll want to read up to the 0 terminator, as I've shown above.

If you *do* want to include whitespace, you're better off using `fgets` (for this problem, you're probably better off using `fgets` anyway):

```
if ( fgets( p, 1000, input ) )
{
  // transform contents of p
}
else
{
  // error or EOF on input
}
```

`fgets` will read up to 999 characters or the newline character, whichever comes first, and properly terminate the string, so you don't need to worry about that.  It will also store the newline character if there's room in the target buffer, so you need to be aware of that.